# Куки и проблемы php

Tags: php, cookie

Очень громко ругается, говорит что:

> Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in 1.php on line 19
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at 1.php:19) in 1.php on line 25

Это при первом запуске как можно поправить код что бы он установил куки и сразу их считал.

```
$check = $_COOKIE['check'];
$check = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#",'',$check);
if(empty($check)) {
setcookie('check',time(),mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2016));
}

if(date("d.m.Y",$check) == date("d.m.Y")){
echo 'Error #1';
$good1 = false;
}
else {
$good1 = true;
setcookie('check',time(),mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2016));
}
```

Comment: > что бы он установил куки и сразу их считал
, у вас значала считываются потом пишутся. Вывод текста уберите еще до самого кода

Comment: ну а как проверять стоит ли кука или нет? может уже стоит а он ее перебьет.

Answer (score 1):

Страница в кодировке utf-8 **без BOM**. Не пойму, зачем все эти проверки, но может достаточно так:

```
$good1 = false; // Не очень ясно для чего она служит (*смотрим ниже)
$check = !empty($_COOKIE['check']) ? intval($_COOKIE['check']) : false;
if(isset($check) && $check > 0){
    // Кука установлена
    // Можно проверять её значение или делать еще что-то
} else {
    // Кука не установлена
    // Ставим её
    setcookie('check', time(), mktime(0,0,0,1,1,16));
    $good1 = true; // *Если переменная служит для для определения именно установки куки, а не её существования
}
```

P.S. Если надо устанавить куки/сессии после какого-то вывода на экран, то используйте [буферизацию](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php)

Comment: intval) еще на PHP 4 пишите?

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, её кто-то отменил в пятых версиях? Или вам сегодня приснилось, что [в документации написано][1] что она считается устаревшей? Шутник...

   [1]:http://us1.php.net/manual/ru/function.intval.php

Comment: все супер как нужно срабатывает сейчас!

Comment: в какой то момент код перестал работать! по не известным причинам мне возможно смена хостинга. просто кука ставиться через этот код никак пишет постоянно $good1 = true; а куки нет!

Comment: @big-vl, сударь, я же не телепат. Попробуйте указать путь? если этого не сделано, да и **httponly** вам тоже не помешает.

    setcookie('check', time(), mktime(0,0,0,1,1,16), '/', false, true);

Comment: @Deonis, Краткий экскурс в историю: IntVal использовался чтобы получить инт типа переконвертировать в предыдущих версиях, потом появились нормальные операторы дял работы с типами и все на них переключились, когда вижу интвал , для меня это признак очень старого процедурного кода. Не только для меня.